# readPDF library tm format issue

Tags: r, pdf

So hello, I am trying to read a PDF but have issues with the format.
The doc and code is below.
The issue is the output doc doesn't respect the original PDF lines. The last item from line 4 appears in line 5. Is that something I can correct?
The reason I am asking is I need to read 1000's of files like this and have this issue in most files.

When using a pdf to excel on the web I dont have this same issue.

thanks

```
URL="http://www.arb.ca.gov/cc/capandtrade/offsets/issuance/cals5047-a-b.pdf"
destfile="filetoconvert.pdf"
download.file(URL,destfile)



doc=readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = destfile),
                                              language = "en",
                                              id = "id1")
issuance2=NULL
issuance2delim=NULL

doc = c(as.character(doc))
```

Comment: are you getting the issue when you view the document or only print in console?

Comment: The document looks fine. My issue yes is when I print the doc on the console.

Comment: It is just a size issue, extend the size of your console. Many times if the console is not able to fit the result in one line it moves it to the next. Let me know if thats the issue

Comment: Dinesh thx for ur help. No really isn't. If I print doc per line, you see that the lines dont correspond. Line 4 has: 7 elements, 5: 8 elements and 6: 1. Qhen printing these 3 lines, you ll see that readPDF for some weird reason creates a lag.